# Why $ \frac{1}{w-z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Theta_n(w)z^{-2\Delta_\phi} G_{\Delta_n} (z) $?

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory

In [*Large N analytical functional bootstrap I: 1D CFTs and total positivity* by Zhijin Li](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.01311) Eq. 4.10 and Eq. 4.11 the author used the following the following identity
$$
\frac{1}{w-z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Theta_n(w)z^{-2\Delta_\phi} G_{\Delta_n} (z)
$$
on the positive contour $C_+$ around the $(1,\infty)$ axis and
$$
\frac{1}{w-z}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Theta_n(1-w)(1-z)^{-2\Delta_\phi} G_{\Delta_n} (1-z)
$$
on the negative contour $C_-$ around the $(-\infty,0)$ axis, where

$$\Theta_n(w)
=\frac{(-1)^n(2\Delta_\phi)^2_n}{n!(4\Delta_\phi +n-1)_n} \frac{1}{w} {}_3 F_2(1,-n,4\Delta_\phi+n-1;2\Delta_\phi,2\Delta_\phi;\frac{1}{w})$$

and

$$z^{-2\Delta_\phi} G_{\Delta_n} (z), 
(1-z)^{-2\Delta_\phi} G_{\Delta_n} (1-z)$$
was a function basis from the conformal blocks.

Could you provide a reference or indication to where the identity came from? What's the subscript $(4\Delta_\phi +n-1)_n$ in $\Theta_n(w)$ for?

Also, the above expression seemed to violate the uniqueness of the expansion in the function spaces, since there were two expansion of the same expression in the same functional spaces. Those the conformal blocks were not entire, the convergences were guaranteed in $|z|<1$. Does that mean the
$\{z^{-2\Delta_\phi} G_{\Delta_n} (z),(1-z)^{-2\Delta_\phi} G_{\Delta_n} (1-z)\}$ are not really a function basis?

Comment: *What's the subscript …* I’m going to guess that $(x)_n$ is a [Pochhammer symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html), but I don’t know CFT so maybe I’m wrong.

Comment: Indeed, $(x)_n = \Gamma(x + n) / \Gamma(x)$. A reference for deriving decompositions like this is https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.08471 which also makes some careful comments about when conformal blocks form a basis.